# Кастомизация <input type="range">

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как `<input type="range">` удалить бегунок и изменить цвет полоски? (аналог progress на скрине)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.range {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: #444;
    height: 3px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.range::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0;
}
   
.range::-ms-thumb {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="range">
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/